# Unable to load DLL the specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport

For a long time I have a problem with a project that I have to implement in mine, I'll explain it to you.

My goal is to call a C ++ class from a C # application (**Project 1**), the problem is that the C ++ project (**Project 3**) is not compatible with CLR.

What I have done so far has been created an intermediate project also in **unmanaged C ++** (**Project 2**) to be compatible with the project 3.

Project 2 consists of a very simple method that initializes a class from project 3 and uses this object for different operations.

I'm working in Visual Studio and it does not give me an error when compiling, but at run time I get the following error:

> Unable to load the DLL file 'PROJECT-ROUTE \ Project2.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
>   in project1.process ()

The thing is that the previous error comes out only when within the project2 method I initialize the class from project 3, if I comment the initialization line then it goes well, I can not understand why between 2 C ++ projects of the same type gives me this type of problems.

Can somebody help me?

thank you

C# Code (Project 1)

```
    private const string DllFilePath = @"PATH_TO_DLL\Proyect2.dll";

    [DllImport(DllFilePath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "process")]
    public extern static void process();

    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    public static string Prox(string a, string b)
    {
        string str = "OK";
        try
        {

            process();
        }
        catch (System.AccessViolationException exception)
        {
            return exception.Message + " " + exception.StackTrace;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message + " " + exception.StackTrace + " ";

        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

Middle proyect Unamanged C++ Code (Project 2)

Project2.h

```
    #include <stdexcept>
    #include "Project3.h"
    using namespace std;


    namespace FinalProcess
    {
        extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl  process(); }
    }
```

Project2.cpp

```
    #include "Project2.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <chrono> // To measure execution time

    namespace FinalProcess
    {
        void process()
        {

            OCTA::Analyzer& ld = OCTA::Analyzer::getInstance(); // <-- Singleton
    // if I comment this line then it goes well
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any exception starting with 0x8 is an invalid pointer (or accessing memory outside the limits).When you register an event the event can occur before (or during the exception of the constructor) any data is available.For example if you have a Window Form project you can have a DGV with initially with rows and columns count set to  -1.When you register an event the event can occur before the DGV create the rows and columns so you have to test in the event that rows and columns count are > zero. It looks like you may be trying to getInstance before WaterAnalyzer constructor is run (or completed).

Comment: @jdweng No, 0x8xxxxxxx means that bit 31, the severity bit is set. That bit indicates success or failure. All `HRESULT` values that indicate an error have that bit set. This error code is in fact a Win32 error wrapped up in a COM `HRESULT`. 0x8007xxxx indicates that this is a Win32 error. And the Win32 error is `0x7F` which is [ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: David : Again you are wrong.  The Win32 error comes from the Intel Exception register where the MSB a memory range error.

Comment: @jdweng https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the information that you present here is correct (and I have my doubts because you've not copied it verbatim as can be seen from the DLL name of `Proyect2.dll`) then the error cannot be that the function `process` is not found. In which case the error has to be in the linking to `Project3`.

Your `Project2.dll` is presumably attempting to link to `Project3.dll` and to a function that is not exported from `Project3.dll`. That would explain the behaviour that you report. This would happen typically if the `Project3.lib` file that you linked when building `Project2.dll` did not match the `Project3.dll` file found by the executable at runtime.

Make sure that the version of `Project3.dll` that is being loaded is up to date and matches the `.h` and `.lib` files you used to build `Project2.dll`.

Rather than give an absolute path of the DLL in your C# code, you just the file name of the DLL. Place both DLLs in the same directory as your C# executable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had Project3's DLL in the same directory as my C# executable but it was out fo date